# Finding the maximum of $G(x) = \int_{x}^{x+a} f(t) \,dt$ using FTOC.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let's discuss with a simple example: $f(t) = -t^2.$

Given $a>0,$ define $G(x) = \int_{x}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt$.

I'm interested in how to find the value of $x$ that maximises $G(x)$.

The direct method is:

$G(x) = \left[ -\frac13 t^3 \right]_x^{x+a} = -\frac13(x+a)^3 - (-\frac13x^3) = \ ...\ = -a\left[\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{a^2}{12} \right],$

which is maximised when $x = -\frac{a}{2},$ as expected.

But this method was only easy because I chose $f(t) = -t^2$. In general, it would appear we would have to use numerical methods to optimise $G(x),$ in particular if $G(x)$ is not easily integrable.

However, is there some trick we can use with the FTOC, that tells us the value of $x$ that maximises $G(x)$?

For example, $G(x) = \int_{x}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt$ achieves a maximum when

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{x}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt\right) = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{q}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt - \int_{q}^{x} -t^2 \,dt\right) = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{q}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt\right) - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{q}^{x} -t^2 \,dt\right) = 0,$

where q is a sufficiently large negative constant. Now, the second term simplifies to $-x^2$ by FTOC. But I'm not certain if/how the first term reduces, or if there is some other trick I am missing here, which can also be applied for more difficult functions $f(t)$?

Comment: Use the chain rule, with the "inner function" being $x+a$.

Comment: Set $F(x)=\int_q ^x -t^2\, dt$ and $g(x)=x+a$. Then your function has rule $F(g(x))$ and, using the chain rule, has derivative $F'(x+a) g'(x)=-(x+a)^2\cdot1$.

Comment: @ David Mitra - I already tried that method. However, when I first tried it, I made a silly mistake, so I thought my method was wrong. Actually with my silly mistake corrected, my method is equivalent to yours and gives the correct answer. But I can't delete this question. So I'll make an answer myself explaining what my silly mistake was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Mitra points out in the comments, the chain rule one would think "should work" here does in fact work.

I made a silly mistake in my working. I let $u=x+a$ so that $\frac{d}{dx}$ can be interchanged with $\frac{d}{du}$, so:

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{q}^{x+a} -t^2 \,dt\right) = \frac{d}{du}\left(\int_{q}^{u} -t^2 \,dt\right) = -u^2 = -(x+a)^2$

but somehow I then made the following basic mistake:

$x^2 - (x+a)^2 = x^2 - (x^2 + 2a + a^2) = ... = 0$,

so I missed an $x$ in the term "$2a$" and got a wrong answer. So I thought my method was wrong.

However, that last term should be $x^2 - (x^2 + 2ax + a^2)$ and then setting this to $0$ gives the correct answer of $x = \frac{-a}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

If your $f$ is continuous then your $G$ is differentiable. Then applying the Leibnitz rule of differentiating under integral you calculate $G'(x)$ equate it to zero and then use the double derivative test to find out the point of extrema. Given your the function, we get
$$ G'(x)=0+(-(x+a)^2)-(-x^2)= -(x+a)^2+x^2= -a^2-2ax=0 \implies x=\dfrac{-a}{2}$$

Comment: Please can you illustrate your answer with an example?